# Bootstrap 3 .col-xs-offset-* doesn't work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap 3 grid system loved it so far and everything was working well, 
I am trying to use col-xs-offset-1 and doesn't work although .col-sm-offset-1 works. 
What am I missing here ?

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">col</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petran/zMcs5/2/

Comment: @Vixed The answer is ***not*** out of date, as the question clearly refers to Bootstrap v3. See current [master](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/css/bootstrap.css#L1738).  For `-xs` being dropped in v4, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41794746/col-xs-not-working-in-bootstrap-4/41795300#41795300).

Comment: I know you're right, but nobody posted an alternative right now ;)

Comment: @Vixed I am reluctant to add a v4 answer to a v3 question. Instead, I edited [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41795300/1891677), as it's a v4 question regarding `col-xs-*` classes.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

Edit: as of Bootstrap 3.1 `.col-xs-offset-*` **does exist**, see **[bootstrap :: grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)**

---

`.col-xs-offset-*` doesn't exist.
Offset and column ordering are only for small and more. (ONLY `.col-sm-offset-*`, `.col-md-offset-*` and `.col-lg-offset-*`)

See the official documentation : **[bootstrap :: grid options](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)**

Comment: I'm not sure if this link is now replaced by newer documentation, but it states that Offsets are available for every device size. It still doesn't work however so I suppose it's still not supported :(

Comment: " .col-xs-offset-* "  Appears to be working fine now.

Comment: `.col-xs-offset-*` does exist in bootstrap 3

Answer (score 26):

Alternatively, you can add an empty div for the xs-offset (would save you having to manage the content in more than one place)

```
<div class="col-xs-1 visible-xs"></div><div class="col-xs-2">col</div>
```

The bootstrap devs seem to be refusing to add those xs- ofsets and push/pull classes, see here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9689

Answer (score 12):

You could get the offset set only for xs devises by negating the higher pixels with 0 offset.
Like so,

```
class="col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-0"
```

Answer (score 6):

A suggestion for when you want to do an offset but find yourself incapable at extra small widths:

Use `.hidden-xs` and `.visible-xs` to make one version of your html block for extra small widths, and one for everything else (where you can still use an offset)

**Example:**

```
<div class="hero container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="hidden-xs col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center">
      <h2>This is a banner at the top of my site. It shows in everything except XS</h2>
      <p>Here are some supporting details about my banner.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="visible-xs col-xs-12">
      <h2 class="pull-right">This is my banner at XS width.</h2>
      <p class="pull-right">This is my supporting content at XS width.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

col-md-offset-4 does not work if you manually apply margin to the same element. For example

In the above code, offset will not be applied. Instead a margin of 0 auto will be applied

Answer (score 3):

This was really frustrating so I wrote a gist you can grab that enables `col-offset-xs-*`.  I also noticed that Bootstrap SASS repo Bower installed this week did not include `col-offset-sm-0` so that is shimmed too but will be redundant in many cases.

[Bootstrap 3 xs offset shim](https://gist.github.com/dylanvalade/7362739)

Answer (score 2):

```
  /*

  Include this after bootstrap.css

  Add a class of 'col-xs-offset-*' and 
  if you want to disable the offset at a larger size add in 'col-*-offset-0'

  Examples:
  All display sizes (xs,sm,md,lg) have an offset of 1
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-3">

  xs has an offset of 1
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-0 col-sm-3">

  xs and sm have an offset of 1
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-offset-0 col-sm-3">

  xs, sm and md will have an offset of 1
  <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-offset-0 col-sm-3">

*/

.col-xs-offset-12 {
    margin-left: 100%;
}
.col-xs-offset-11 {
    margin-left: 91.66666666666666%;
}
.col-xs-offset-10 {
    margin-left: 83.33333333333334%;
}
.col-xs-offset-9 {
    margin-left: 75%;
}
.col-xs-offset-8 {
    margin-left: 66.66666666666666%;
}
.col-xs-offset-7 {
    margin-left: 58.333333333333336%;
}
.col-xs-offset-6 {
    margin-left: 50%;
}
.col-xs-offset-5 {
    margin-left: 41.66666666666667%;
}
.col-xs-offset-4 {
    margin-left: 33.33333333333333%;
}
.col-xs-offset-3 {
    margin-left: 25%;
}
.col-xs-offset-2 {
    margin-left: 16.666666666666664%;
}
.col-xs-offset-1 {
    margin-left: 8.333333333333332%;
}
.col-xs-offset-0 {
    margin-left: 0;
}

/* Ensure that all of the zero offsets are available - recent SASS version did not include .col-sm-offset-0 */
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .col-sm-offset-0,
    .col-md-offset-0,
    .col-lg-offset-0 {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/dylanvalade/7362739

Answer (score 2):

As of Boostrap 4.x, just as **col-xs-6** is now just **col-6**

**offset-xs-6** is now just **offset-6** (and `col-lg-offset-2` is now `offset-lg-2`).

Already tried it, definitely works.

Answer (score 1):

Its not working because `col-xs-offset-*` is mentioned out of the media query. if you want to use it, you have to mention all the offset (eg: `class="col-xs-offset-3 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-0"`)

But this is not right, they should mention `col-xs-offset-*` in the media query

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrap css used in the jsfiddle link, dont have the css for col-xs-offset-*, thats why the css are not been applied. Refer the latest bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're putting .name class instead of nameclass

Answer (score 0):

instead of using col-md-offset-4 use instead offset-md-4, you no longer have to use col when you're offsetting. In your case use offset-xs-1 and this will work. make sure you've called the bootstrap.css folder into your html as follows  .

Comment: all of these answers above are wrong this is and I can promise you the best answer to anyone that has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

// it works in bootstrap 4, there was some changes in documentation.We dont need prefix col-, just **offset-lg-3** e.g.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="offset-lg-3 col-lg-6"> Some content...
   </div>
</div>
```

// here doc: 
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#example-offsetting-columns

Comment: I believe the OP is asking about the `xs` offset, not offsets in general. I can't find anything in the docs about an xs offset, nor can I get it to trigger by adding xs offset classes in the DOM. Hopefully I'm wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: @JasonFry Lol i dont care, but what problem i described general solution-problem:)

Answer (score 0):

As per the latest bootstrap v3.3.7 xs-offseting is allowed. See the documentation here [bootstrap offseting](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting). So you can use

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">.col-xs-2 .col-xs-offset-1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone makes the same error I did before stumbling on this page, that is,  adding `CSS` reset rules (like [the very popular reset by Eric Meyer](http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/)  used on millions of websites) ***after*** including bootstrap.

Also, perhaps I should point out that such reset won't be necessary with bootstrap given bootsrap actually implements the *normalize.css v3.0.2* reset.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the dot in front of your class so it looks like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">col</div>
```