# How to use offset in twitter bottstrap grid layout

Tags: grid, twitter-bootstrap-4

I am tying to apply an offset to a column in twitters bootstrap framework using this code

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately the column is not getting affected by the offset class.
Every other class is working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This code works for me. Are you using the latest Bootstrap version? At least past version 3.1 according to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18853308/bootstrap-3-col-xs-offset-doesnt-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you just want to update your version of bootstrap to the latest version. I was able to view your code in an mvc project and it displayed right for me. Here is another question with references to the offset class and bootstrap versions: [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357137/bootstrap-col-md-offset-not-working).

I can't see any other reason why your code would not work unless you have another class in a css file that has an alternate definition for one of your class names.

Comment: Seems to be related to the beta Bootstrap 4 version. I switched back to Bootstrap 3 and now everything worked just out of the box. Thanks guys.